# Add a header to a retrofit request without an Interceptor

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I have a retrofit api interface where one of the calls requires OAuth1 authentication and the others do not. I am trying to find a way to add the `Authentication` header without using an `Interceptor` for a few reasons.

1. At the time the OkHttp Client is created I wont know OAuth1 keys and the client is used for other things too.
2. It is only one request that needs OAuth1 authentication

What I was trying to do is wrap the interface call in a `Call` and then adding the header before I process

```
val call = api.getRecentTweetsV1("$query -filter:replies -filter:retweets")

val oauth = Oauth1Signing.Builder()
    .consumerKey(consumerKey)
    .consumerSecret(consumerSecret)
    .accessToken(token)
    .accessSecret(tokenSecret).build()

val authHeader = oauth.signRequest(call.request())
call.request().headers.newBuilder().add("Authorization", authHeader).build()
val headers = call.request().headers

response = call.execute().body()
```

The problem is I don't see the header getting added in, the `call.request().headers` value is always empty after I try to add it in.

I cant use the `@Header` parameter in the interface call because the `OAuth1Signer` (modified version of [this](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/f26f19732f0c5907e1ab#file-oauth1signinginterceptor-java), I removed the Interceptor usage) takes in a OkHttp Request object to build the header.

Is there another way to add the header after the request has been built?

Comment: "and the client is used for other things too" -- creating a separate `OkHttpClient` from an existing one is trivial: call `newBuilder()` on the existing one and configure from there. Set up a dedicated `OkHttpClient` instance for this particular Retrofit interface that has the interceptor. "At the time the OkHttp Client is created I wont know OAuth1 keys" -- the interceptor merely needs to know where to get the keys from at the time of a request. It does not need to know the keys at the time you create the `OkHttpClient` instance.